# What language to use in Mariadb Stored procedure?

Tags: mariadb

What language do you use to write stored procedures/functions in Mariadb?
Like PL/SQL in oracle, is there an equivalent language in Mariadb?
Thanks

Comment: Read **[MySQL Stored Programs and Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-views.html)** and this: **[MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html)**

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB follows the MySQL coding format. You can use the way we write in MySQL.
Also you can use MySQL workbench as a client to smooth work.

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures and functions are written in SQL. Refer to MariaDB's [Programmatic and Compound Statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/programmatic-and-compound-statements/) and [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/create-procedure/) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As of MariaDB 10.3 (GA since 25. May 2018), a subset of PL/SQL is actually supported in stored procedures and functions with `SET sql_mode=ORACLE`.

See this page for details:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql_modeoracle-from-mariadb-103/